# Protobuf-net how to serialize List<T>

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

Here is my current code for serialization / deserialization

```
// SERIALIZE
using (var file = File.Create(@"..\..\SavedPCInfo.bin"))
{
    Serializer.Serialize(file, pcs);
}

//DESERIALIZE
if (File.Exists(FileName))
{
     using (var file = File.OpenRead(@"..\..\SavedPCInfo.bin"))
     {
          pcs = Serializer.Deserialize<List<PC>>(file);
     }
}
```

Where `pcs` is a list of `PC` objects. As of now I am getting an error when I deserialize:

> No parameterless constructor found for PC

I have no idea why it requires a parameterless constructor for deserializing, but I just wanted my deserialization to work. Any idea on how can that be achieved? I seem to be doing something wrong here.

Comment: I would consider serializing an array instead of a custom collection type such as List<>. You need to serialize the data, not the type.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot seem to see any difference. I prefer lists because of the ease of performing iterative tasks on its items. Unless there is a hidden danger in this I might reconsider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple options:

1. Create a private parameterless constructor in `PC`. It will be called on deserialization.
2. Apply the `[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]` attribute to `PC`. In that case, an object will be instantiated in an uninitialized state.

   Use this one with caution: if you initialize fields to some default values in your class outside of any constructors, these initialization won't happen.

   Example:

   ```
   [ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
   public class PC
   {
       private int _something = 42;

       public int Something { get { return _something; } }

       public PC(string foo)
       {
       }
   }
   ```

   In this case, `Something` will return `0` on a deserialized object.

Comment: Option 1 solved it, but why is a parameter-less constructor necessary?

Comment: @Jer because protobuf wouldn't know how to instantiate the object otherwise (it doesn't know what parameters to supply to your constructor). The second solution uses a totally different means of creating the object (`FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`).